# R 2.15 install in Redhat

Tags: linux, r, installation, redhat

I am trying to install a local copy of R on a server without admin privileges. I know ***almost nothing*** about servers, or linux. I can easily access a copy of R by typing "R", however the server I am working off of only has an old copy of R (v2.10.1). I need at least v2.14 to run my scripts, although I would prefer to install the most recent release.

As far as I understand, my server runs Redhat e15 x86_64 GNU/Linux. I have the server mapped to my windows computer, and tried doing a regular install of Windows R onto the server, but when I try and run the R.exe file I get an error stating I "cannot execute binary file".

I found on the CRAN website what I think I should download:

Under the linux installation... redhat/e15/x86_64

But the folder only contains v2.10. I found this thread about installing R on Redhat, but I am still at a loss for how (if possible) to install/build my own copy of R.

Comment: There isn't a `10.14` version of R. You could compile your own version but that will require a pile of development libraries and a compiler, which often tend to be missing from production servers.

Comment: It would appear that the person who compiled those rpms has stopped providing this service, probably because R is now available as a package either in RHEL or EPEL, the Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux. That doesn't help you - nor would the rpms from CRAN even if they were up to date - as you need to be or become root to install the rpm or the package via yum.

Comment: You'll need to provide a lot more information about the environment you are operating under/in in order for us to help you. Why don't you speak to the person that *is* root on that server and to explain why you need the new version of R?

Comment: My supervisor told me just to download my own copy because the person maintaining the server is really backed up and will not be able to do it anytime in the near future. I can read/write anything I want under my own folder, I just do not have any idea where to start. If I knew what other information to give, I would. Thanks for your replies.

Comment: OK, forget the Linux server the only options involve some level of running such a system and/or compiling from source. Do you have your own computer to install on to - say a Windows or MacOS desktop/laptop? That would be much easier. Why do you need the Linux server?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18820/discussion-between-dayne-and-gavin-simpson)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Generally, building R from source and installing it into your homedirectory is quite easy (I do this too at work). The procedure roughly boils down to the following procedure:

- create a directory in which you want to install R, e.g. `~/progsandlibs/`. You can also use this directory for all other custom software you install.
- Download [R from CRAN](http://cran.at.r-project.org/src/base/R-2/R-2.15.2.tar.gz).
- Extract the `tar.gz` file you downloaded using `tar`
- Go into the `R-2.15.2` directory.
- Give the following commands:

  - `./configure --prefix=~/progsandlibs/ --enable-R-shlib`
  - `make`
  - `make install`
- Add `~/progsandlibs/bin/` to your `PATH` environment variable. Easiest is to add a line to your `.bashrc`: `export PATH=~/progsandlibs/bin/:$PATH`.

If all the steps above worked correctly, you have R installed, and you can start it from your terminal.

Comment: I agree that its quite easy (once you get the hang of it) but installing the required dependencies is not trivial without root. However, given that there is an old version, this should not be impossible, just time consuming and potentially error prone.

Comment: @richiemorrisroe I did not have to install any additional packages on my work computer, but this might not be true for our OP. If the number of packages is limited, one might try and install the missing packages from source. However, as you said, this can get quite tricky...

Comment: When I try the ./configure I get: configure: error: No F77 compiler found :(

Comment: The short answer is that you need to install a Fortran compiler. For a better answer you should create your own question which includes much more detail.