# Error running R in Linux

Tags: linux, r

I followed this [R 2.15 install in Redhat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13146852/r-2-15-install-in-redhat) step by step
to install R in Cent os 6.3, got this error in the intermediate step, i have created the progsandlibs

```
dir in ~

[root@localhost R-2.15.2]# ./configure --prefix=~/progsandlibs/ --enable-R-shlib
configure: error: expected an absolute directory name for --prefix: ~/progsandlibs
```

Then i tried just `./configure`

```
configure: error: in `/root/progsandlibs/R-2.15.2':
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
```

I installed gcc compiler through yum

later when i run `./configure` i got this error

```
 configure: error: No F77 compiler found
```

Any idea what needs to be installed ?

Comment: The error said that you don't have a fortran compiler. try to install like you did with `gcc`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

run the following command as *root* before configuring **R**:

```
yum install gcc
```

this command will install the latest F77 compiler by GNU, then you should be able to install **R** as you mentioned in your question.

---

**If you need the old g77** for whatever reason please run this (as *root*)

```
yum install compat-gcc*
```

`g77` compiler has stopped development so [it is replaced by `gfortran` in `gcc`](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/fortran/2007-01/msg00619.html) > 4.2.

---

Comment: did $yum install gcc-c++ and got rid of sanity check error successfully now $./configure --prefix=~/progsandlibs/ --enable-R-shlib
configure: error: expected an absolute directory name for --prefix: ~/progsandlibs
so tried $./configure
checking for history_truncate_file... no
configure: error: --with-readline=yes (default) and headers/libs are not available
so tried $./configure --enable-R-shlib
checking for history_truncate_file... no
configure: error: --with-readline=yes (default) and headers/libs are not available
Please let me know where i am wrong

Comment: just a question: did you tried `yum install R`? Is there a good reason to not use standard packages?

Comment: with regard to your second error: you need to provide an absolute path for your prefix: use `./configure --prefix=/root/progsandlibs/ --enable-R-shlib`

Comment: I tried $yum install R                                           Setting up Install Process
No package R available.
Error: Nothing to do

Comment: ‍ ‍‍‍`sudo apt-get install fort77‍‍‍‍‍‍`

Answer (score 21):

Try installing the **gfortran**.

For example: **apt-get install gfortran**

Answer (score 0):

I follow to @furins but it not work for me. So, I tried do install (update) gcc with instruction in [here](https://forum.abinit.org/viewtopic.php?t=3511) and it work for me (centos7). To give you a fish, try

```
yum install gcc gcc-gfortran
```