# install R mapreduce rmr2 on centos

Tags: linux, r, mapreduce, centos, rhadoop

I am having problem installing [rmr2](https://github.com/RevolutionAnalytics/rmr2) on centos, yum command by default installs R version 2.15, and rmr2 is dependent on [Rcpp](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/index.html) library which is only compatible with R 3.0 or later. This is my os version :

```
$ uname -or
2.6.18-348.16.1.el5 GNU/Linux

$ lsb_release -irc
Distributor ID: CentOS
Release:        5.9
Codename:       Final
```

install.packages('Rcpp') return `ERROR: this R is version 2.15.2, package 'Rcpp' requires R >= 3.0.0`. I am not able to find R 3.0 for centos on their download [page](http://cran.rstudio.com/)

`yum install R` returns :

```
Setting up Install Process
Package R-2.15.2-1.el5.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13146852/r-2-15-install-in-redhat

Comment: that have http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/redhat/el5/x86_64/ R-2.10.0-2.el5.x86_64.rpm, those files arent updated since 2009, so I am not sure they have R 3.0 for centos.

Comment: http://gradstudents.wcas.northwestern.edu/~jaf502/blog/2013/03/11/installing-r-in-linux/

Comment: The last link suggests: `su -c 'rpm -Uvh http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/5/i386/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm'; sudo yum update; sudo yum install R` for El5/CentOS 5

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9468164/problems-installing-r-on-linux-centos-6-2

Comment: i installed older version of Rcpp and it worked with R2.15.